# Degrees of freedom in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a (first-order, ordinary, constant coefficients, homogenous) differential equation

$$ 0 = Ay + By' $$

we can obtain the general form of the solutions

$$ y = Ce^{-\tfrac{A}{B}t} $$

If we specify an initial value for $y$, as in IVPs, then we choose among the family of functions above – essentially, adjust $C$ – the one that meets this criterium as well.
But for a second-order (ordinary, constant coefficients, homogenous) diff. eq., say

\begin{align*}
0 = Ay + By'' \\
\therefore y = Ce^{\pm t\sqrt{-\tfrac{A}{B}}}
\end{align*}

if we are given extra constraints (initial values of $y,y''$, say), instead of just "adjusting the parameters in the general solution to meet this new demand", what we have to do is find a linear combination of two "basis solutions" that will meet the new demand. Correct? The reason I ask is that I might have considered for a second that we just had to adjust the parameters in the general solution.

Indeed, even in the first-order case we had to do that (find the appropriate combination of the basis solutions), but by virtue of the fact that in the first-order case the solutions was a one-dimensional vector space, this amounted to just adjusting the parameter $C$ in the general solution. Correct? Just checking my reasoning.

Comment: The general solution is $y = C_1e^{ t\sqrt{-\tfrac{A}{B}}}+C_2e^{- t\sqrt{-\tfrac{A}{B}}}$. Given two conditions, two equations are derived. They are linear equation considering the unknowns $C_1$ and $C_2$. Solve the linear system for $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: "adjusting the parameters" and "finding a linear combination of the basis solutions" are more or less the same thing.

Comment: @Dylan: Exactly, I hadn't realised that. My realisation of this fact was narrated in the last paragraph.

Comment: It wasn't clear that you did, as your last paragraph only mentions the first-order case. Especially in the second to last paragraph when you asked if you could do one instead of the other. In any case, you should try to make your question more succinct, since I'm still not sure what you're really asking.